# Need assistance regarding REST service authentication in objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, rest

I am trying to consume rest based web service for the first time so I searched for tutorials and examples I found these [link1](http://blog.hardikr.com/tech/rest-objc/) & [link2](http://blog.mugunthkumar.com/articles/iphone-tutorial-authenticating-with-a-restful-service-using-nsurlcredential/)

My colleague created a simple rest service, first without authentication I successfully fetched the json formatted data but same service with form based authentication I am unable to call it which include adding id, password in http header `[request addValue:@"id:password" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];`, using `willSendRequestForAuthenticationChallenge` but no success.

I also found tons of [RestKit](http://restkit.org) articles but its problem is its too heavy, my requirement for project is not that complex.

Please any one can provide good and complete tutorial or any way to import Restkit required functionality not the whole 16mb framework?

Comment: I have had a similar issue and it was solved by formatting the header data as JSON. Check out using NSJSONSerialization for this.

Comment: please can you provide a code snippet. I am unable to connect to web service after that json come into scene...

Answer (score 0):

I recommend AFNetworking ,it is easy to integrate and very reliable.

You can use AFURLConnection -setAuthenticationChallengeBlock: to respond to authentication challenges.